# OWIN redirect not hitting controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect, owin

Trying to implement OWIN/Open ID (we tried MSAL but came up against some bugs) in an legacy MVC App - This is a mixed authentication app with forms auth as primary and Open ID as an option so all we're trying to get is the ID_TOKEN and match that with our local user profile.

The problem I'm having is the redirecturi is not hitting the controller action but is instead redirected and I can't figure out why - I call the auth challenge, pick my account and then this. I can use postman and it hits the controller fine.

As you can see from the network grab it calls /callback with the right payload, gets a 302 and redirects. Thinking it might be to do with XSS or something as it's getting the 302 before hitting the controller.

thanks for any help - Just run out of ideas on this one.

here's the redirecturl (/callback). Note this is .Net framework, not Core.

```
/// <returns></returns>
        [AllowAnonymous]
        //[HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [DisableCors]
    
        public async Task<ActionResult> callback ( string code = "",string id_token = "" )
        {

            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }**strong text**
```

and the Startup_auth

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = authority,
                ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = secret,          
                PostLogoutRedirectUri =logoffUri,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                },
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile

            };
```

And the network log

[image: Network log]

Comment: Did you ever get this working as I have the exact same problem, although in .NET Framework not Core.

Comment: Never did. Banged my head off a wall for weeks and finally gave up. Maybe ours is a strange setup as it's hybrid - We have forms auth and wanted to add a secondary sign in with openId. Ours is Framework also. It's a legacy app that we've in the process of moving to core.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, let me say I empathize with your situation after making every possible mistake over the last 6 months with Microsoft Identity Web. From your question I am not sure if you have given up on Microsoft Identity Web and gone with ASP.NET Core Identity or... something else. In any case, let me share the top three things that came to my mind in reading your question:

1. When you register those OpenId Connect authentication event handlers, be sure to call the previous event handlers as they sometimes do essential things. I found out the hard way (after pursuing item 3 below in desperation).
2. Authentication with Azure AD does redirect to the Azure AD STS, then the Azure AD STS redirects back to your application. At this point, the framework performs its processing, then fires the event handlers and you get access to the tokens (or error notifications).
3. When all else fails, get a very simple working example of your chosen auth architecture (there are so many which makes it hard) and migrate your code bit by bit until you have a working app. Inevitably you will encounter the problem far before you need to actually migrate the entire app. But that will always work... eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the input - This thing is wreaking my head trying to figure it out. I am creating a new scratch project to see if I can get it going, then come back to the main project.